# Python Index error (out of bounds) accessing element in 2D array

Tags: python, csv, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to access an element of a 2d array created from data in a csv file. I can print the array fine.

When I try to access the array to find a certain element (i.e. a number from 'row' 1 'column' 5)  it throws the error:

```
C:\Users\AClayton\Current\python begin\code_tester.py in create_alldata(whichfile)
37     array_data=np.array(all_data)
---> 38     nb=array_data[1][5]
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

if anyone could help that would be great

```
def create_alldata(whichfile):
    open_file = open(infile, 'rb')                       
    csv_current=csv.reader(open_file)                     
    all_data=[]                              
    np.array(all_data)
    for row in open_file:         
        all_data.append(row)                            
    open_file.close()
    array_data=np.array(all_data)
    nb=array_data[1][5]
    return array_data,    


path=raw_input('What is the directory?')
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv')): 
    create_alldata(infile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read multidimensional data from a CSV, use the [`numpy.genfromtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) or [`numpy.loadtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) functions, depending on how complete your CSV file is (use the former if row length varies, the latter if constant and uniform).

You are instead trying to build a multidimensional `numpy` array manually, which as you discovered doesn't quite work like that.

```
import numpy

def create_alldata(whichfile):
    return numpy.genfromtxt(whichfile)
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, I made the change you suggested, but it threw the error:

IndexError: too many indices

Comment: @AshleighClayton: then you don't have a multidimensional numpy array.

Comment: I'm trying to access 2 cols now using: 
a = np.array(all_data)
col=a[:,[0,1]] , however I retrieve the first two colums?

Comment: `genfromtxt` *already* returns a numpy array, why are you using `np.array()` still?

Comment: And it is not clear what you asking. You are trying to access 2 columns, and the slice you show returns the first two columns, yes. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: sorry I meant to say it gives me the rows. sorry ignore the previous code and assume I did a=create_alldata(whichfile) col=a[:,[0,1]]